# Custom post types filtered by taxonomy using REST API v2

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, rest-api

I have the following situation:

I created a custom Post Type names **Works**.
And also attached to it custom taxonomy named **Work Types**

Here is the code

```
function rk_work_post_type(){
$labels = array(
    'name'               => 'Work',
    'singular_name'      => 'Work',
    'add_new'            => 'Add Work',
    'all_items'          => 'All Works',
    'add_new_item'       => 'Add Work',
    'edit_item'          => 'Edit Work',
    'new_item'           => 'New Work',
    'view_item'          => 'View Work',
    'search_item'        => 'Search Work',
    'not_found'          => 'No items found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No items found in trash',
    'parent_item_colon'  => 'Parent Item'
);
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'thumbnail',
        'revisions',
        'comments',
    ),
    // 'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-hammer',
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'show_in_rest'       => true,
    'rest_base'          => 'works',
    'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller',      
);
register_post_type('work',$args);
}

add_action('init','rk_work_post_type');


function rk_work_taxonomies() {
//add new taxonomy hierarchical
$labels = array(
    'name' => 'Work Types',
    'singular_name' => 'Work type',
    'search_items' => 'Search Types',
    'all_items' => 'All Work Types',
    'parent_item' => 'Parent Type',
    'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Type:',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Work Type',
    'update_item' => 'Update Work Type',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Work Type',
    'new_item_name' => 'New Work Type Name',
    'menu_name' => 'Work Types'
);

$args = array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'work_type' ),
    'show_in_rest'       => true,
    'rest_base'          => 'work_type',
    'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Terms_Controller',      
);

register_taxonomy('work_type', array('work'), $args);
}
add_action( 'init' , 'rk_work_taxonomies' );
```

The issue that i have is that i cant find a way to get the **Works** filtered by **Work Type** using REST API v2

I read that after some wordpress update filter query was removed from REST API.
So what is the proper way to do this now? Can you provide some example please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, the solution was:

```
example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/works?work_type=10
```

It views the work_types as id's.
You can view the id's in:

```
example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/works
```

Comment: to retrive by slug just add _slug at the end of category slug. work_type_slug={slug}

Comment: Adding _slug to the end of the param doesn't work for me. I'm using WordPress 4.9.8, REST API v2. Using the id works great though.

If you want to get the single term from the REST API based on the slug, then you use slug={term_slug} eg:

`example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/works?slug=work-type-slug`

Comment: **In order for it to work, you need `'show_in_rest' => true,` on `register_taxonomy`.**

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy could you please point to some documentation about it? The technique doesn't seem to work with WP 5.3.2

Answer (score 5):

I installed the WP REST Filter plugin and then i'm able to filter post by category slug like:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/my_custom_posts?filter[my_custom_taxomony]=my_custom_taxonomy_slug
```

in your case:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/works?filter[work_type]=building
```

Comment: please mark as solution. ;)

Comment: I think use a plugin is not "the solution"

Answer (score 4):

If you really need to use slug as url parameter you can add a custom filter, take a look to [rest_{$this->post_type}_query hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/)

You can do something like that (post_type: work, taxonomy: work_type):

```php
/**
 * Filter work post type by work_type slug
 *
 * @param array $args
 * @param WP_Rest_Rquest $request
 * @return array $args
 */
function filter_rest_work_query( $args, $request ) { 
    $params = $request->get_params(); 
    if(isset($params['work_type_slug'])){
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'work_type',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => explode(',', $params['work_type_slug'])
            )
        );
    }
    return $args; 
}   
// add the filter 
add_filter( "rest_work_query", 'filter_rest_work_query', 10, 2 );
```

and then

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/work?work_type_slug=slug01,slug02
```

Comment: Using this code will only work if there are no other taxonomies being passed in. (Setting $args['tax_query'] explicitly like this will overwrite any other values of the tax_query which may be set.) You will need to check to see if the array is defined, and extend it if so, rather than overwriting it.

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

This link help

It includes get_posts() method
Which is used to get post

Pass post type in argument